# Remove value from gwt combobox using selenium / webdriver

Tags: gwt, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test GWT webapp using selenium. I have a testcase where i should remove value from combobox and save the element with null value in it (options in combobox are does not have null value)

My problem occurs when i remove the values. Then GWT opens the combobox to choose value. Normally Escape works on keyboard and firefox closes the combobox, but .sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE)) does not... and after entity save it uses old value.

I've tried selenium.type, driver.findElement....clear(); , but gwt is still using the previous value.

Any ideas?
Thanks:)

Comment: Why do you have such a test case?It doesn't make sense to write functional tests for something which can user never do (like altering the source code of application).

Comment: but the user can do it, he can put null value in this combobox... how the app is constructed is not my thing to judge ;)